# The second derivative of a mixture of two normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Assume $μ1$ and $μ2$ are the two means and the standard deviation is $σ$ for two normal distribution.

The probability of x in the mixture of these two normal distributions is

$$
p(x)=0.5N(x;μ1,σ)+0.5N(x;μ2,σ) 
$$

How can I prove the second derivative is strictly less than zero for $|μ1−μ2|<2σ$

Really appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the derivatives of the mixture density?  (The answer to the first one does not require any calculation--it follows directly from the symmetries of the distributions and the differentiability of their densities--but the answer to the second one does appear to need some calculation.)

Comment: And what, then, prevents you from drawing the desired conclusions?  What expression did you get for the second derivative?

Comment: Right now, I have an inequality function I can not solve.
For x > $\frac{\mu1+\mu2}{2}$, $((x-\mu1)^2 - \sigma^2)\exp^{\frac{-(x-\mu1)^2}{2\sigma^2}} + ((x-\mu2)^2 - \sigma^2)\exp^{\frac{-(x-\mu1)^2}{2\sigma^2}} < 0$

Comment: Can you give some tips to solve a function like this? Thanks!

Comment: Because the exponential is positive, you may divide both sides by it, leaving a quadratic inequality in $x$.  Its solution is elementary.

Comment: Thanks! But I have a typo in my function, the right one is that for $x > \frac{\mu1+\mu2}{2}$，$((x-\mu1)^2 - \sigma^2)\exp^{\frac{-(x - \mu1)^2}{2\sigma^2}} + ((x-\mu2)^2 - \sigma^2)\exp^{\frac{-(x - \mu2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Comment: If this is the case, I can not simply divide the exponential, what should I do?

Comment: Yes, that's a little trickier.  Try setting $y=(x - (\mu_1+\mu_2)/2)/\sigma$ and rexpressing everything in terms of $y$.  You can then easily move the exponentials to one side and the quadratics to the other.  Apply Calculus.

Comment: I ended up this inequality function. For $y > 0$, $-\exp^{-(\frac{\mu2-\mu1}{\sigma})y} > \frac{(y - (\frac{\mu2-\mu1}{2\sigma}))^2 - 1}{(y + (\frac{\mu2-\mu1}{2\sigma}))^2 - 1}$, I had hard time finding what is the next step. Any tips? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Is it equal to prove that for y >0, $(1 - (y - \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma})^2)((y + \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma})^2 - 1) > 0$

Comment: I think the reason you're running into difficulties at this stage is that your question is not formulated with sufficient clarity--and as currently stated, what it posits is not true. You *have* to impose some restriction on $x,$ because the second derivative of any continuous density defined on an infinite interval *must* change sign.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Really appreciated. I found out what I am missing. For the last question, can you give me some tips about this statement, "the second derivative of any continuous density defined on an infinite interval must change sign"?

Comment: The argument comes down to basic Calculus reasoning: no change in sign implies the first derivative is monotonic, which implies its absolute value must have a nonzero lower bound either as you approach $\infty$ or $-\infty$, which implies the density increases (or decreases) without bound in that direction, which implies the distribution function is unbounded, and that's a contradiction. BTW, your formulation still is incorrect because it makes no assertion about $x.$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help from @whuber. Here is the answer to my own question.
The original statement is not true. It should be rephrased to this,

$$
For\ |\mu2-\mu1| < 2\sigma\\
p''(x) < 0, if \begin{cases}\sigma < x < (\mu2 - \mu1) + \sigma\\-\sigma < x < (\mu2 - \mu1) - \sigma\end{cases}
$$

Proof:

After some calculation, the second derivative is

$$
p''(x) = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^3}[(1 - \frac{(x - \mu1)^2}{\sigma^2}) \exp^{\frac{-(x - \mu1)^2}{2\sigma^2}} + (1 - \frac{(x - \mu2)^2}{\sigma^2}) \exp^{\frac{-(x - \mu2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}]
$$

Set $y = \frac{1}{\sigma}(x - \frac{\mu1 + \mu2}{2})$

$$
p''(y) = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^3}[(1 - (y + (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2) \exp^{\frac{-1}{2}(y + \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma})^2} + (1 - (y - (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2) \exp^{\frac{-1}{2}(y - (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2}]
$$

By removing the constant, then the objective function is

$$
((y + (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2 - 1) \exp^{-y(\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{\sigma})} + ((y - (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2 - 1) < 0
$$

We can organize this function into

$$
\exp^{-y(\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{\sigma})} < \frac{(1 - (y - (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2)}{((y + (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2 - 1)}
$$

Because the exponential function must be positive, we should try to prove that

$$
(1 - (y - (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2)((y + (\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}))^2 - 1) > 0
$$

Because the 4 roots in this function are

$$
y = \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}\pm1, -\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma}\pm1
$$

Finally, we can find the interval of y to make this function larger than 0

$$
\begin{alignedat}{2}
-\frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma} - 1 < y < \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma} - 1\\
1 - \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma} < y < \frac{\mu2 - \mu1}{2\sigma} + 1
\end{alignedat}
$$

After substituing y with $\frac{1}{\sigma}(x - \frac{\mu1 + \mu2}{2})$, we can get

$$
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\mu1 - \sigma < x < \mu2 - \sigma\\
\sigma - \mu1 < x < \mu2 + \sigma\
\end{alignedat}
$$